# Extracting data with string::erase in c++

Tags: c++

I'm working on data reading and writing on csv's.

So I came up with this problem.

I'm taking a line from csv with `getline(myfile, myline);` and I send myline to a function in order to extract all the useless information and keep the part between some certain ',' (commas) I need.

I implemented this with this function:

```
int get_id(string myline) {
    int id;
    size_t pos;
    pos = myline.find(",");
    myline.erase((myline.begin() + pos), myline.end());
    stringstream converter(myline);
    converter >> id;
    return id;
}
```

I have only one `myline.find(",");` because the data I want is the first of the line.

Example of my csv format:

```
id,name,age,address
```

So I'm having an error at `myline.erase()` I think because when I put it in comments it ran smoothly. I'm wondering is it correct that I added a `size_t` to `myline.begin()` ? (no compilation errors). Is it also correct as a mindset for extracting data ?

The error is the following:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error' what(): basic_string::_S_create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example, with the provided data does not cause an error. There will however be a problem if the input contains no comma, such as you will encounter if you try to tokenize the last element. [std::string::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) returns [npos](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos) if no match is found. `npos`'s value is the largest value of `std::size_t` (if you are using the default allocator). Adding this value to `begin` will give you an invalid iterator.

Simply compare with `npos` before erasing to avoid this issue.

```
if (pos != string::npos) {
    myline.erase((myline.begin() + pos), myline.end());
}
```

Comment: yeah, it sounds very reasonable, because I call this function in a big loop. But I'm wondering how, because I check for eof.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to see why you are seeing the problem. My suggestions:

Remove the `erase` function call. If the line contains a number followed by a `,`, then the stream extractor will stop at the `,` any way. Just use:

```
int get_id(string myline) {
   int id = 0;
   stringstream converter(myline);
   converter >> id;
   return id;
}
```

If you must erase, you may want to add another check.

```
int get_id(string myline) {

   // Erase only if there is a "," in the line.
   atuo pos = myline.find(",");
   if ( pos != std::string::npos )
   {
      myline.erase((myline.begin() + pos), myline.end());
   }

   int id = 0;
   stringstream converter(myline);
   converter >> id;
   return id;
}
```

Comment: hmm.. yeah, checking for `pos` definitely can save me. The negative of the problem is that if pos gets to be -1 means that this string shouldn't even be there.

Comment: @Theo.Fanis, you'll have to come up with a strategy for dealing with that problem. At least this makes sure that you don't call `erase` when you shouldn't.

Comment: Yes I know, now that this problem is solved I will go back to my main. thank you very much !

Comment: @Theo.Fanis If there is no coma, then it's up to you to define what that means. The most likely case though is that it's the last token of the string (the previous comas have been erased). In that case, the absence of a comma means that the whole thing is a token.